# How to compare two date fields in a document, one of them being embedded in an array?

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to compare two fields with specified $type = "date" however when i try to query i get 0 results.
My end goal is to output all documents with s.status =6 and s.time < r.

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [ 
 {  item: "canvas","r" : {"$date" : "2019-05-23T00:00:00.000+0000"},"s" :[{ "status" : 1, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:03:10.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 2, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:03.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 4, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:06.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 5, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:07.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 6, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:09.000+0000" } } ]},
 { item: "paper","r" : { "$date" : "2019-05-24T06:00:00.000+0000" }, "s" :  [ { "status" : 1, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:03:10.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 2, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:03.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 3, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:06.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 4, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-25T05:05:07.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 6, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-25T05:55:09.000+0000" } } ] },
 { item: "stone","r" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T05:00:00.000+0000" }, "s" : [ { "status" : 1, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:03:10.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 2, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:03.000+0000" } } ] },
 { item: "mass","r" : {"$date" : "2019-05-24T06:00:00.000+0000"},"s" :[ { "status" : 1, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:03:10.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 2, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:03.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 4, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:06.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 5, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:07.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 6, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-24T06:06:09.000+0000" } } ] },
 {item : "paper","r" : {"$date" : "2019-05-24T06:00:00.000+0000" },"s" :[ { "status" : 1, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:03:10.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 2, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:03.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 4, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:06.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 5, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-23T23:05:07.000+0000" } }, { "status" : 6, "time" : { "$date" : "2019-05-24T06:06:09.000+0000" } } ] }
]);
```

what I've tried-

```
db.inventory.find({"s": {"$elemMatch" : {"status" : 6,"time" : { "$lt" : ISODate(this.r)}}});
```

I'm getting no error butt also 0 results.

Comment: The field "r.$date" is of type string, not a Date type. So is the date defined in the sub-document within the "s" array. Those need to be of type date to compare (as dates).

Comment: @prasad_ `r` is of type `ISODate` i.e. `{ "r": ISODate("2019-05-23T00:00:00.000+0000")}` and `{ "r": {"$date" : "2019-05-23T00:00:00.000+0000"} }` are same and `r.$date` is not even a field.

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma After running the `db.inventory.insertMany( [` in the question post, try these commands: `db.dates.find( { "r.$date": { $type: 'date' } } )` _and_ `db.dates.find( { "r.$date": { $type: 'string' } } )`. The result shows that the `$date` field is a string type (and not a date type field).

Comment: @prasad_ The point which I am trying to convey is that `{$date:""}` is an extended form of `ISODate("")`. Thus, instead of querying on `r.$date`, we can directly query on `r`. Please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma { $date:"" } is not an extended form of ISODate(""). It is an extended format of JSON.

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma Extended JSON types are useful, say, when you export a collection using `mongoexport`. There is no equivalent to field types like `ObjectId` or `Date` in JSON. So, the exported output, a JSON file, is created using these extended JSON types. Try exporting a simple document with `ObjectId` and `Date` fields (BSON types). The resulting export JSON file, will have data as extended JSON.

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma [continued from the previous comment] The exported JSON file can be imported (using `mongoimport`) into a MongoDB collection; the import  recognizes these extended JSON and converts them into corresponding BSON types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$elemMatch` doesn't support comparison with fields till now.

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.inventory.find({
    $expr:{
        $gt:[
            {
                $size:{
                    $filter:{
                        "input":"$s",
                        "as":"doc",
                        "cond":{
                            $and:[
                                {
                                    $eq:["$$doc.status",6]
                                },
                                {
                                    $lt:["$$doc.time","$r"]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            0
        ]
    }
}).pretty()
```